# How to send an array of strings to web server using Haskell Network.HTTP.Simple?

Tags: rest, http, haskell, post

I need to send an array of strings via POST call to a server as described here:
http://pulsar.apache.org/admin-rest-api/?version=2.6.0&apiversion=v2#operation/setNamespaceReplicationClusters

The array should look like

[
"string",
"string"
]

I would imagine the code should look like this:

```
httpPostSetClustersNameSpace :: String -> String -> IO Int
httpPostSetClustersNameSpace endpoint clustersAsString = do
  request <- parseRequest $ "POST " ++ endpoint
  response <- httpLBS $ setRequestBodyLBS "????" request
  let status =  getResponseStatusCode response
  return status
```

Not sure what to do, I review this write up, but not sure how to represent the array in ByteString.

https://phuoc-thanh.github.io/2018/chapter04-reveal-the-secret/

I can do JSON like this:

```
newtype ClusterInfo = ClusterInfo [String]
instance ToJSON ClusterInfo where
    toJSON (ClusterInfo clusters) = object
        [ "clusters" .= clusters
        ]

httpPostCluster :: String -> ClusterInfo -> IO Int
httpPostCluster endpoint clusterInfo = do
  request <- parseRequest $ "POST " ++ endpoint
  response <- httpLBS $ setRequestBodyJSON clusterInfo request
  let status =  getResponseStatusCode response
  return status
```

But an array of string is not JSON.  So, I can not use setRequestBodyJSON.

Comment: `The array should look like [ "string", "string" ]` That looks like JSON to me.

Comment: Doesn't json requires key value?  like {clusters: ["a","b"]}?

I could do this:

```
newtype ClusterInfo = ClusterInfo [String]
instance ToJSON ClusterInfo where
    toJSON (ClusterInfo clusters) = object
        [ "clusters" .= clusters
        ]
```

I don't think the server is epxecting {clusters: ["a","b"]}.

Comment: `{"clusters": ...}` is a JSON object, and it doesn't seem to be expecting a JSON object. `["a", "b"]` is a JSON array, which seems to be what it expects. Not every JSON value has to be an object, it can just be an array or a string or a number. Try `toJSON (ClusterInfo clusters) = toJSON clusters` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Based on DarthFennec's suggestion, the solution for me is:

```
newtype ReplicationClustersInfo = ReplicationClustersInfo [String]
instance ToJSON ReplicationClustersInfo where
    toJSON (ReplicationClustersInfo clusters) = toJSON clusters

setClustersNameSpace :: ReplicationClustersInfo -> String -> String -> String -> IO Int
setClustersNameSpace replicationClustersInfo host tenant namespace = 
  do
    let endpoint = setNamespaceReplicationClustersEndpoint host tenant namespace
    request <- parseRequest $ "POST " ++ endpoint
    response <- httpLBS $ setRequestBodyJSON replicationClustersInfo request
    let status =  getResponseStatusCode response
    return status
```